# How can I use an external hardware RNG in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, devices, random

I would like to use an external hardware RNG which supplies entropy via network socket.  FreeBSD does not support external RNG/entropy source in the kernel, but does in user space. Ok, that's fine if I'm building my own application to utilize the external entropy source - but how can I implement it so existing applications which use `/dev/random` would also use my extra entropy source? My understanding is the answer is you can't — but would love to be wrong on this.

Answer (score 1):

When you take a look at the [implementation of /dev/random in 11.0](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/releng/11.0/sys/dev/random/randomdev.c#L246) you will notice that with the support of the new random algorithms (fortuna has replaced yarrow), there is also support to feed the entropy with a write call to `/dev/random`.

The 10.x releases do not support this write call. The man page [previously said for 10.3](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+10.3-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) that writes will be silently ignored and [in the 11.0 man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE) this passage has been removed. Unfortunately, there is no explanation that feeding entropy is possible by writing to the device.

In my opinion you should ask on the mailing lists, because this seems to be a serious security-relevant topic for you and I have just found some information which might be not enough to be absolutely sure about this new functionality and all the gotchas that might exist there.

Comment: Link to 10.3 brings up current version of random. Furthermore, going back to 10.3 I can't find where it says that writes will be ignored.  Please clarify source?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the website, but I found the link to random(4) on 10.3 and corrected it.

Comment: thanks, but I still don't see where it says that writes will be ignored. Here (https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/bsdcon02/full_papers/murray/murray_html/) it says that "writing to /dev/random... In actual fact, the data written is ``harvested'' using the harvesting calls, with the proviso that the entropy is estimated to be nothing... If the user is the superuser, then closing the device after a write will cause an explicit reseed."

which if I understand it correctly means that as superuser you can both write entropy here AND cause an explicit re-seed. thoughts?

Comment: It's in the first sentence of DESCRIPTION "..., but discards data written to it."

Comment: Thanks Martin.. glossed over that while searching for the word "ignore" :)

That does totally go against the writeup of murray's paper on yarrow.. but I guess FreeBSD may have implemented it differently. I'm also trying to get to the bottom of how to add entropy in versions prior to 11 and am seeing conflicting info on the interwebz..